# Timeout in C# UT Visual Studio does not work

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, unit-testing, selenium-chromedriver

I have problem with Timeout attribute ([MSDN doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.timeoutattribute?view=visualstudiosdk-2022)) for tests in C# in Visual Studio 2019.

For some reasons sometimes it does not end test if declared timeout is reached - for example: test is set to timeout after 2h (in milliseconds) and i found out that after 2 days is still stuck.

Tests are using selenium and web driver to walk on some pages. In some (yet unknown) cases code is stuck and I would expect that timeout will occur and stop such tests...

In our code we have 2 types of test declarations:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
[TestMethod]
[Timeout(7200000)]
public void Test1() {...}

[TestMethod]
[Timeout(7200000)]
public Task Test2() {...}
```

In some test we are using also `[DataSource]` attribute to feed test - I am aware that timeout will work for all tests combined in that case.

Of course I will try to find the real reason why test is stuck on some methods, but still I expect timeout to work.

Any idea what the reason could be that timeout is not working?

Comment: Have you tried to create dummy tests with 1 second timeout and 2 seconds sleep / delay?

Comment: How are you running these tests? Can you include information about that?

Comment: @PeterCsala - created simple test to check if Timeouts works and it works - ends after 10 sec. Code:
```
[TestMethod]
        [Timeout(10*1000)]
        public void Timeout10Sec()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
        }
```

@GregBurghardt running from command line
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" "pathToTests.dll" /TestCaseFilter:Name="TestName" /logger:trx /settings:"testSettings.tests.runsettings" /TestAdapterPath:"pathToFolder"`